# Customize New Experience SharePoint List with InfoPath?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, infopath, modern-experience, flow

Is this possible?

I have created a new style list because the MS Flow works 100000000 times better than workflows.

But now that I have switched to this experience, I cannot find anything related to InfoPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a supplement, from the SharePoint Designer feature deprecation article, Microsoft said that:

Users who have previously leveraged SharePoint Designer to create custom Forms are instead able to utilize **PowerApps** for this purpose.

**PowerApps** is an easy and powerful tool that allows users operating in the **SharePoint Online Modern experience** to create and edit custom Forms for SharePoint lists and document libraries right from a browser window. **PowerApps does not require traditional coding knowledge or any additional app downloads such as InfoPath.**

Similar issue for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/349538/deprecation-of-sharepoint-designer-custom-forms.html

Answer (score 0):

**No**. SharePoint online modern experience does not support InfoPath customizations.

If you want to use InfoPath, you have to switch back to classic experience.

**Modern options**:

1. [Show or hide columns in a list or library form](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide)
2. [Configure the list form - using JSON](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration)
3. [Customize a SharePoint list or library form by using Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form)